# Swift - Array won't save elements

Tags: arrays, swift

I am using a function to add an element to an array using `array.append()`. Oddly, the array does not save the element and when checking the count, it will be empty. When putting the same code into a Playground, it will work like it should.

Class 1 (where the function is to add an element):

```
class FirstClass {
    var array:[(Int, Int, String)] = []

    func add(var1:Int, var2:Int, var3:String)
    {
        array.append((Int, Int, String)(var1, var2, var3))
        println(array.count)
    }
}
```

Class 2 (from where I call the function):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        FirstClass().add(1, 2, "xxx")
        FirstClass().add(2, 1, "xxx")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

I can see that the array is empty, because I always print the count after every adding.

Has anyone else experienced something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `FirstClass` each time you add an element to the array, so the previous one is lost. You should create one instance only of `FirstClass`, and call the `add` method on that:

```
var firstClass = FirstClass()
firstClass.add(1, 2, "xxx")
firstClass.add(2, 1, "xxx")
```

If you want `firstClass` to be persisted in the class instance, declare it as a property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var firstClass = FirstClass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.firstClass.add(1, 2, "xxx")
        self.firstClass.add(2, 1, "xxx")
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would I access the same instance from another class then? Say I create an instance of FirstClass in ViewController1 and then I want to access that instance from ViewController2? Cheers! @Antonio